# Send tables via email using R

Tags: r, email

I have created two tables that I would like to send in body email using R.

Currently I am using mailR package and have managed to send one of the tables, however I can't find a way to include both tables in the email. Please note that the two tables have different number of columns (and so I can't append them). Any suggestions? Thanks

```
send.mail (from = "email",
       to = c("email"),
       subject = "Something",
       body = print(xtable(tablename), type = "html",
                    format.args = list(big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = "."),
                    size="\\fontsize{10pt}\\Arial",
                    booktabs = TRUE,
                    include.rownames = FALSE), 
       html = TRUE,
       smtp = list(host.name = "hostname"),
       attach.files = c(paste0("G:/",
                               format(Sys.time(), "%d-%b-%Y"), ".xlsx")),
       send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you considered rendering a html file with Rmarkdown, knitr, etc. and including the rendered html file as mail body?

Comment: @snaut you can't send html using send.mail though?

Comment: `print.xtable` returns html code, so you are already sending html code. I'm not entirely sure which headers and enclosing tags are allowed in the html parts of mails, but `knitr` can render the inner html without header, so this should not be a problem.